# What (bw) laser printer to buy for rare use, brand without driver problems, Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: printing

I've only found information about printers or brands (like Canon) known to cause problems with Ubuntu.

Since my parents asked me to buy them a printer now (and I myself have an old Canon printer (!)), I don't know which brand or model to choose that will work like a charm.

They only want to print very occasionally, so I've read a small b&w laser printer would be best for them. They just want something to plug in and print. No fuss.

Can you recommend a brand or simple laser printers that you know work with Ubuntu 20.04 without any special driver installation?
(I'm keeping the LTS on their laptop as long as it is supported, so 20.04 will probably stay there for a while.)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Site policy not to make hardware recommendations.

Comment: Occasional-use laser printers are often fussy, regardless of the OS. Toner doesn't like to get old, needs to be shaken occasionally, and performs poorly in humidity, and the cheap parts are...well, cheap.

Comment: Our Canon works great.

Comment: I apologize for violating site policies. I didn't know this kind of help was not possible, but I might have re-phrased the question to "where can I find information on / databases on printers that work", had I known of it, or known those databases exist. Thanks a lot to those who helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's refer you to [openprinting.org's printer database](https://openprinting.org/printers)

There you can search for what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

> Since my parents asked me to buy them a printer now (and I myself have an old Canon printer (!)), I don't know which brand or model to choose that will work like a charm.

Any modern printer (one you buy in the shops) will work with Ubuntu. Absolutely guaranteed. I'll refund your purchase price if it does not.